# Two UART Devices (One for USB and one for Bluetooth)

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, uart

I need to make the Raspberry Pi communicate with the Arduino via USB Cable. From this, I will use the port on the USB which supports Serial Communication. However I also need to make the Raspberry Pi communicate through Bluetooth in a Mobile App via Serial Communication as well. Since both Serial devices use different ports according the the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B documentation, can it communicate at the same time? (The Arduino to Raspberry Pi and Raspberry Pi to Mobile App). The Bluetooth uses the /dev/ttyAMA0 port then I will use an USB port to connect the Pi to the Arduino.

Example using pySerial library.

serialArduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

serialBluetooth = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600)

Comment: You're confusing the situation by conflating a USB gadget device with a UART.  `/dev/ttyACM0` and `/dev/ttyAMA0` would be two different and independent hardware devices.  The fact that both devices are treated as serial terminals is inconsequential.  The I/O system is designed to handle multiple devices with minimal interference between those attached devices. *"can it communicate at the same time?"* -- Only if you have well-written software.

Comment: Since they are separate, I can communicate with them at the same time by the serial object I defined in my sample code in the question above right? I just need to check if serial data is available in either of the two objects then I will read it.